# CSV file not found despite specified path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying a project as a beginner. It is driving me nuts because I keep getting minor errors that paralyze the whole execution. Here's an error that has been plaguing me.

```
### SOLUTION
## 1. Introduction of dataset
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# This lets us see many columns in the output
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.cp36-win_amd64.pyd", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
V\000~Ã\000\000ëtA¸P\000\000\000H»Ì\000H

builtins.FileNotFoundError: File b'data.csv' does not exist.
```

Why do I get this error even though the csv file exists?

Comment: does `data.csv` exist in the program's current directory?  Use `import os;print(os.getcwd())` to find out what the program thinks the current directory is.

Comment: Your data.csv is already present , but is that same path where you are executing this program... Print current path using os.getcwd()

Comment: Thanks Mark, Shivam. I noticed that I had idiotically opened the file from a different directory. Now, after using os.getcwd(), I realized my mistake. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide absolute path for the file.

For example: `pd.read_csv("/path/to/the/file/data.csv", ...)`

Or if you want to read the file from current directory:

```
import os
import sys

csv_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.executable)) + '/data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, index_col=0)
```

Comment: It is not mandatory to provide absolute path always. If you know where the file is from current path then you can provide relative path as well